# How to remove lines between cells in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

There is probably a really easy thing that I am missing here, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the lines that divide the cells in a WPF DataGrid.  I have looked at most of the Default Template, but I can't seem to find what I am looking for in there.  Does anyone know where in the template this kind of stuff might be?  Is there a simple property to set ?

Answer (score 1):

DataGrid.GridLinesVisibility = DataGridGridLinesVisibility.None;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.gridlinesvisibility.aspx

Comment: I knew it was something easy... duh..  So what about the template part of the question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" Grid.Row="1"  GridLinesVisibility="None"/>
```

I hope this will help.